# preg_match not matching more than 1 character at a time in string extracted from PDF

Tags: php, regex, string, pdf

I used a library called pdfparser to extract text from a PDF. I successfully have done so, however I'm having some wierd issues with the extracted text. The string looks like this:

```
Invoice
Date
1/8/2016
Invoice #
1679105
Bill To
etc...
```

And when I use `preg_match` to match a single character, like the letter i, I get a capital I in return, and if I used `preg_match_all` I get an array of capital and lowercase letter I in the order you would expect. But if I try "in", I get nothing, when it should return "In" in "Invoice". This applies to any letter combination I try in the search.

This is what converts the PDF data (from an email attachment) into a ASCII string:

```
$parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
$pdf    = $parser->parseContent($body);
$pages  = $pdf->getPages();
$pdfText = "";
foreach ($pages as $pageNum => $page)
    $pdfText .= "\n\tPage $pageNum\n".$page->getText();
```

And this is what searches through the document:

```
$regex = "/invoice/i";
preg_match_all($regex, $pdfText, $test);
echo "<h2>PDF Text</h2><pre>$pdfText</pre>";
echo "<pre><b>Search Results for $regex</b>".print_r($test,1)."</pre>";
```

This will return 0 results. Even something as simple as `$regex = "/[0-9]{2,}/"` wont return any results

Edit: I copied and pasted the text that was displayed in my browser by $pdfText, then pasted it into my php file as a string and searched it with the exact same code. The search works perfectly fine.

Edit 2: **Found the issue.** But I still need help. I used the function `bin2hex( $pdfText )` and found that the word "invoice" has the hex code "0049006e0076006f006900630065". When properly represented, it's actually "496e766f696365". So there is a character between every single letter in my PDF string who's hex value is "00". How would I get rid of them all?

Comment: You are missing a semi-colon after `$regex = "/invoice/i"` ... but assuming that's not what the issue is...

Comment: Thanks, fixed. Not the issue though.

Comment: What is the value of pdfText if you do `echo htmlentities(print_r($pdfText, true));` ?

Comment: It looks exactly the same as before.

Comment: I used `bin2hex` and found "00" between every letter. So `0049006e0076006f006900630065` is what "invoice" in my PDF is, and `496e766f696365` is what it should be. How do I fix this?

Comment: try... `preg_replace('/[\x00]/', '', $string);`

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. You can answer the question with that and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix characters that contain an unwanted hex value, you can replace it using this method.

```
preg_replace('/\x00/', '', $string);
```